# How to select a specific export from file with a variable?

Tags: javascript

I am using react and working with a basic export file containing contracts, here's how it looks like:

```js
export const contract1 = ....
export const contract2 = ....
export const contract3 = ....
export const contract4 = ....
```

Then in another file, I import them with:

```js
import * as P from "../filepath"

const function = (contractVariable)=>{
     let contract =  P.contractVariable;
...
}
```

I want to select the contract being exported according to the variable in my function.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can dynamically access object properties.

```js
let contract =  P[contractVariable];
```

Comment: Nice! see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable#4244912) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Answer (score 0):

Answer above is very helpful.  I found another issue which was my variable was actually only the id (1, 2, 3, or 4).  With that help I got it by using:

```
let contract = P.[`contract`+`${contractId}`]
```